# Callback with window.setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to return a some metadata found on a page in a google-chrome extension. The background.js makes a request to the website.js page for the metedata. The request is made right when the page is updating content, so I have to check to make sure that data has been modified before I return. Here is my code:

```
var checkMeta = function(){
    var title = $(".playerBarSong").text();
    var artist = $(".playerBarArtist").text();
    var album = $(".playerBarAlbum").text();
    var art = $(".playerBarArt").attr("src");
    if (previousTitle != title || previousArtist != artist || previousAlbum != album || previousArt != art){
        previousTitle = title;
        previousArtist = artist;
        previousAlbum = album;
        previousArt = art;

        currentMeta.title = title;
        currentMeta.artist = artist;
        currentMeta.album = album;
        currentMeta.art = art;

        window.clearInterval(intervalId);
        sendResponse(currentMeta); //Does not return value to the extension
    }

};

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        if (request.request == "meta"){
            currentMeta = request.meta;

            intervalId = window.setInterval(checkMeta,250)
            //Some sort of callback?
        }
    }
);
```

Any solution in vanilla JavaScript or jquery would be appreciated.

Comment: where `sendResponse` function is?

Comment: It is passed to me from the addListener

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like `checkMeta` function doesn't know about `sendResponse`. One solution is to make `sendResponse` global like this: `window.sendResponse = sendResponse;`. Another solution is to pass it to `checkMeta` function as argument like this:

```
 intervalId = window.setInterval( function(){ checkMeta(sendResponse);},250)
```

and change the `checkMeta` definition like this:

```
var checkMeta = function(sendResponse){
```

Give it a shot

Comment: Hmm, I get this weird error now:
Could not send response: The chrome.runtime.onMessage listener must return true if you want to send a response after the listener returns  (message was sent by extension biiifagddabbaebndafhpehefabhhpgn).

Comment: I can use window.sendResponse from within the addListener, but using it from checkMeta gives that error.

Comment: @FranzPayer Did you not try returning true in the `onMessage` handler?

Comment: I did, it looks like the value is being returned but the error keeps firing regardless. I'm going to mark this as correct. That issue is probably a separate problem.

Comment: @FranzPayer yes it seems something specific in work with extensions. i can't help you here , may be you should try to ask for help on some google' developers forum

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
//.....

return true;    // try it :)
});
```

[chrome.runtime reference](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage)

*Function to call (at most once) when you have a response. The argument should be any JSON-ifiable object. If you have more than one onMessage listener in the same document, then only one may send a response. This function becomes invalid when the event listener returns, **unless you return true from the event listener to indicate you wish to send a response asynchronously** (this will keep the message channel open to the other end until sendResponse is called).*